# Why does OpenCV constructor work in iPhone5 and not iPhone6/iPad?

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, constructor

I have the following code:

```
CGFloat data[6] = {0.0f,1.0f,2.0f,3.0f,4.0f,5.0f};
cv::Mat warp_mat( 6,1, CV_32FC1,data);

for (int i=0;i<6;++i)
     printf("%f, ",warp_mat.at<float>(i));
```

This code works fine when I run it on an iPhone5 and on the iPhone5 simulator.
However it prints gibberish when I run it on iPhone6/iPad and their simulators.
Can anyone tell me why?

I fixed it using this code:

```
cv::Mat warp_mat( 6,1, CV_32FC1);
    for (int j=0;j<6;++j)
        warp_mat.at<float>(j)=data[j];
```

but I am concerned there are other issues like this. Any advice\comments\ideas would be appreciated here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `sizeof(CGFloat)` is not equal to `sizeof(float)` on 64 bit systems.

```
CGFloat data[6] = {0.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f};
cv::Mat warp_mat(6, 1, CV_32FC1, data);

for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    printf("%f, ",warp_mat.at<CGFloat>(i));
```

or

```
float data[6] = {0.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f};
cv::Mat warp_mat(6, 1, CV_32FC1, data);

for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    printf("%f, ",warp_mat.at<float>(i));
```

Comment: Bit embarrassing that I didnt even notice I was using a CGFloat instead of a float. Well spotted, thanks!